# Проблема с кодировкой в сообщениях об ошибках

Tags: кодировка, visual-studio-2015, typescript

При компиляции TypeScript сообщения об ошибках выводятся вопросиками. Русская VS 2015 и русская же windows 10, если какая-нибудь возможность пофиксить эту багу или по крайней мере поменять язык не переустанавливая VS?